# Facebook Comments Plugin Not Working

Tags: facebook, comments

I integrated the HTML5 code onto my code:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/de_DE/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=MY_APP_ID";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

and

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://mydomain.com" data-width="470" data-num-posts="2"></div>
```

It is being displayed correctly and I can comment, BUT every Comment seems to stay "local". Meaning, when one User comments, only he can see his comments and no one else. I tried it with a few different users and each user only sees his own comments. What might be the issue?

Comment: Try running your page in the Facebook debugger: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Answer (score 2):

"MY_APP_ID" is probably related to an application currently in sandbox mode.
Such application's activity is shown only to users related, admins, testers etc.
Check APP's settings for this property and disable sandbox mode.